# Jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am just trying to print a error message if someone leaves the text field blank using jquery.But it is not being displayed.
This is html code:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
     <tr>
    <td>
   <label>Name</label></td>
   <td> <input class="required" type="text" name="name" id="name" /><span>(required)</span></td>
     </tr><tr>
    <td><br/><label>Address</label></td>
    <td><input class="required" type="text" name="address" id="address"/><span>(required)</span></td></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var requiredFlag = ' * ';
    $('form :input').filter('.required').next('span').text(requiredFlag).end();
    if ($(this).is('.required')) {
       if (this.value == '') {
       var errorMessage = 'This is a required field';
                             };
            $('span></span').text(errorMessage).appendTo($(this));
                             }; 
});
```

May be i am missing something.
Help experts.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your jquery code, you should create a loop for each input elements and then use the this object. You're using $(this) incorrectly

Comment: Why don't you want to validate form after submit? Also you can use jquery validation plugin - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example. P.S. and what an id 'span></span'? looks like there are many errors. Try to reproduce example from the link below.

Comment: what exactly you think is in js "this"? this contains the context but since you are not iterating over any collection, or calling it withing another function/class that this - is the basic context - the windows (or document?) object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `this` in your code refers to `window/document` object not the `input` elements;
2. There are some typos in your code => `$('span></span')`;
3. There is no `event handler` in your code for validating the `inputs`
4. You have span elements in your markup and there is no need for generating a new one
5. You can use the form `submit` event for validating the inputs
6. The `:input` selector has been deprecated

Try this:

```
var errorMessage = 'This is a required field';
$('form input.required').next().text('*');

$('form').submit(function(){
   var errors = 0;
   $('input.required', this).each(function(){
       if (this.value == '') {
          $(this).next().text(errorMessage);
          errors++;
       }
   })
   if (errors > 0) {
     return false // prevents the default action of the event if there are errors
   }
})
```

1. [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
2. [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
3. [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good selector:  `$('span></span')`. Use jquery [Siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
selector, and change the span text with .text() or .html() function
http://api.jquery.com/html/