# Do not submit form before jquery validate is okay

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I am looking for a way, so that my `FormMethod.Post` Dosen't submit, before jquery validation is done. I have tried by making it so that the button just is at `disabled`, and then remove disable on keydown, if form is okay. But that didn't work, and neither isn't secure. What can i do?

**Html**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_Kontakt", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <b>Facebook Url</b>
            <input id="FacebookUrl" name="FacebookUrl" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <b>Steam Url</b>
            <input id="SteamUrl" name="SteamUrl" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button id="SendBtn" class="btn btn-success pull-right" onclick="return validateUrl();">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Jquery/Javascript**

```
function validateUrl() {
    facebookURL = $("#FacebookUrl").val();
    steamURL = $("#SteamUrl").val();
    var facebook = /^(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?$/;
    var steam = /(?:https?:\/\/)?steamcommunity\.com\/(?:profiles|id)\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/;
    if (facebook.test(facebookURL)) {
    }
    else {
        alert("Ikke et facebook gyldigt url!");
    }
    if (steam.test(steamURL)) {
    }
    else {
        alert("Ikke et steam gyldigt url!");
    }
    return facebook.test(facebookURL);
    return steam.test(steamURL);
}
```

**ANSWERE**

```
return facebook.test(facebookURL) && steam.test(steamURL);
```

Comment: return can be called once in a function. After that the function execution ends. Do you mean:  return facebook.test(facebookURL) && steam.test(steamURL);

Comment: Thanks alot @Striker That helped!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery form validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006344/jquery-form-validation)

Answer (score 0):

There is an "onsubmit" event that allows you to control form submission http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp

Comment: Dosen't work, i followed "Strikers" Comment and that worked :)

Comment: Using the "onsubmit="validateUrl()"> was not working, it did still submit form, becuse i had 2 return values :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put the inputs and button in a form element and use the `pattern` and `required` attributes in combination with the `:invalid` selector the browser can do the validation for you:

```js
/* Add the .focused class when the user focuses
an input to only show the error message once */
$("#the-form input").focus(function(){
  this.classList.add("focused");
});
```

```css
.input-error-message {
  color: red;
}

/* Show elements with the class .input-error-message
if they come after an input with invalid data if the
user isn't typing or if it has not been focused yet */
:invalid:not(:focus).focused + .input-error-message {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <form class="col-sm-6" id="the-form" onsubmit="return isValid()">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <b>Facebook Url</b>
            <input id="FacebookUrl" name="FacebookUrl" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?$" required/>
            <div class="input-error-message" hidden>Ikke et facebook gyldigt url!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <b>Steam Url</b>
            <input id="SteamUrl" name="SteamUrl" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="(?:https?:\/\/)?steamcommunity\.com\/(?:profiles|id)\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/>
            <div class="input-error-message" hidden>Ikke et steam gyldigt url!</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button id="SendBtn" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Wasen't the answere i was looking for, but thanks alot for telling me! I see that i can do it with alot less code :)

Comment: This works great in modern browsers but if you need to support old ones I would recommend your solution.