# How to check validation form before submit in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, validation

I use [JQuery form validation](http://www.formvalidator.net). But i need validation form before submit
with click on tag `<a>`.

For example:

```
<form action="/registration" method="POST">
 <p>
    User name (4 characters minimum, only alphanumeric characters):
    <input data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="min4">
  </p>
  <p>
    Year (yyyy-mm-dd):
    <input data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  </p>
  <p>
    Website:
    <input data-validation="url">
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="">Check before registration</a>
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;">
  </p>
</form>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $.validate({
      lang: 'es'
   });
</script>
```

If form is not any error show submit button.

How to check validation form before submit in jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006344/jquery-form-validation)

Comment: You would just run a lot of conditionals inside of a function that is running either on keyup or on the form submission. Checking the input value length, checking for the index of http: || https: in the url input etc.

Comment: @lumio Hi, Your answer is completely wrong ... I'm sorry

Comment: So what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to validate as you type?

Comment: @kenny, Hi, i create form and before submit need check validation form in my website. How to check?

Comment: The answer given will validate before allowing the submit, the only difference is if you use that answer you will have to amend it to fit your source code and add validation to the inputs you wish to validate.

Comment: So you haven't really done anything so far have you.... other than copy/paste the basic example from http://www.formvalidator.net/ Maybe read the documentation http://www.formvalidator.net/#configuration or look at more examples. Don't expect others to do all the work for you, this isn't a free writing service.

Comment: @lumio, I need check form without refresh page.

Comment: @mySun please read the accepted answer :)

Comment: @lumio , This answer use submit in code `$('form').submit(function(){`... !

Comment: Please clarify your question then. As you are stating now you want to validate before form gets submitted. If you want to send the form data after validation via AJAX look at this [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960245/881032)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommended**: Just have the submit button at place, and put the rules for validation in html and call the $.validate() as provided with library. That way library can work with more stability.

But if you want to do it programmatically, and show submit button only after a validate button, this might be helpful, http://www.formvalidator.net/#advanced_programmatically
with this code to trigger the validation

```
// This will keep using use default options
// and validate on submit or if user presses enter
$.validate(); 


// This will validate on clicking verify button and show a submit button
$("#verify-button").on("click", function(e){
    if($("#myform").isValid()){
         $("#submit-button").show();
    }
});
```

A fiddle snippet https://jsfiddle.net/cad2xjb0/2/

Comment: That is already handled by $.validate function that is run without any event, in the Form Demo of the library it triggers validation before submission. I tried pressing Enter and it did the validation. Can you confirm @NewToJS ? http://www.formvalidator.net/#reg-form

Comment: :P but that also makes the validate button and then submit button deal unnecessary, just have submit button and let library handle the validation as it is supposed to.

Comment: Thank you, But don't work this code for me... please explain more

Comment: This will trigger the validation on click event on an element with id "verify-button" and show the submit button with id "submit-button"

Comment: $("#passenger-form").validate(function(valid, elem){
            if(valid) {
                console.log('11');
            }
        });  don't work for me...

Comment: Updated the code :P had made a mistake @mySun also included an ugly but working js fiddle.